# JNI spec mentions methods added in JDK 1.3 that don't exist

Tags: java-native-interface

In the [JNI spec at this location](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#wp5833) there is the following note:

> Note
>
> As of JDK/JRE 1.1, programmers can use Get/ReleaseArrayElements functions to obtain a pointer to primitive array elements. If the VM supports pinning, the pointer to the original data is returned; otherwise, a copy is made.
>
> New functions introduced as of JDK/JRE 1.3 allow native code to obtain a direct pointer to array elements even if the VM does not support pinning.

The second sentence is the puzzling one, because I can find no methods that do that. All array access functions have the potential to make a copy, even GetPrimitiveArrayCritical(). The more readable version of the spec, "The Java™ Native Interface: Programmer’s Guide and Specification" is no help here, because it was published in 1999, before JDK 1.3 was released. And as far as I can tell, no JNI methods were added at all in 1.3 - searching for the string "1.3" in the spec only finds this one use!

Does anyone have any idea what this note is referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Is there any way to pass a Java Array to C through JNI without making a copy of it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231599/is-there-any-way-to-pass-a-java-array-to-c-through-jni-without-making-a-copy-of). The answer there is that the *new* function is **GetPrimitiveArrayCritical()**. It does not guarantee no-copy , but does not require pinning to provide access in place.

Also relevant is the comment to linked question: DirectBuffer is *guaranteed* to provide in place access on any VM.

Comment: I do not believe GetPrimitiveArrayCritical() is what they are referring to. First, the note explicitly says that the "new functions" allow native code to obtain a direct pointer **even if the VM does not support pinning**, while the docs on GetPrimitiveArrayCritical() say "These restrictions **make it more likely** that the native code will obtain an uncopied version of the array, even if the VM does not support pinning." Secondly, GetPrimitiveArrayCritical() was introduced in JDK 1.2.

Comment: After another re-reading of the spec, I think you are right. All the other "note" boxes refer to some older methods that appear before the note, and then introduce new functions that immediately follow the note. This would follow that pattern. I'm guessing the note is just badly worded, and also typo'd the JDK version.