# Android NDK - fill Java's byte array from C code

Tags: java, android, c, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have a code which needs to be run from C (uses C library, plus it's performance is crticial and involves tons of loop iterations).
The code needs to decode an image and run some operations on it. Final result should be Android/Java's bitmap.

Due to high resolution and a need to display a picture without any scaling this creates performacne issue.

I have pre-allocated bitmaps which I'm reusing, to avoid too many allocations and garbage collections. Currently I've managed to do all stuff required for proof of concept, I've done it like this:

```java
public static void fillNativeBitmap(String src, Bitmap bmp) {
    byte[] nativeBytes = getNativeBytesARGB8(src);
    bmp.copyPixelsFromBuffer(ByteBuffer.wrap(nativeBytes));
}

JNIEXPORT jbyteArray JNICALL
notImportantForQuestion_getNativeBytesARGB8(
  JNIEnv *env,
  jclass clazz,
  jstring src
) {
    char *src_file;
    unsigned char *imptr;
    src_file = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, src, NULL);
    const int total_pixels = xxx;
    static unsigned char mptr[xxx];
    decodeOneStep(src_file, &imptr); //uses lodepng to decode bitmap file
    
    doStuffWithImage(imptr, mptr);

    jbyteArray result = (*env)->NewByteArray(env, total_pixels); //here - unnececeary allocation for GC?

    (*env)->SetByteArrayRegion(env, result, 0, total_pixels, mptr);
    (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, src, src_file);
    free(imptr); //I can live with that

    return result;
}
```

I'd like to reuse Java's bitmap buffer, pass it to C and fill it there. However, method for accessing java's array from C takes pointer to "isCopy". Accessing copy of Java's array does not work for me at all, as I don't need java's data from C context, I just need C context to fill Java's data.

What method should I use in this case? How to achieve it in most optimal way? I'm trying to optimise for performance and stability, the later one includes keeping number of allocations as low as possible.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. If I understand correctly, you want to pass a java array to your C code and then use the filled array in java?

Comment: Yes, I've found a sample way to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24649808/how-to-pass-byte-array-from-android-java-class-to-jni-c-ndk
But that method seems unsuitable, because of pointer to "isCopy"

Comment: Take a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231599/is-there-any-way-to-pass-a-java-array-to-c-through-jni-without-making-a-copy-of

Comment: Thanks a lot! Looks like it should solve my issue!

Comment: If you want direct access to the Bitmap's pixels then perhaps you should use the [native `AndroidBitmap` functions](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/bitmap#androidbitmap_lockpixels).

Comment: Sure thing :) Happy I was able to help

Comment: *Due to high resolution and a need to display a picture without any scaling this creates performacne issue.*  How do you know where in the code your performance issue is?  Have you profiled your code and know where the problems are?  Down to even knowing which machine instructions take the most time?  If you haven't done that, you are just guessing where the problems are, **and you are probably wrong**.